# SlickNav: How to make the desktop menu's child ul drop down on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-plugins, menu

I am using SlickNav as a multi-level dropdown menu. When I resize the browser to display the mobile menu, the child  items drop down. How do I do this with the desktop menu? Is this built into the plugin or does it require custom jquery?

My code below:

HTML:

```
 <ul id="Menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>About Us
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">item 6</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">item 7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#Menu').slicknav();
});
```

I have not made any changes to the plugin css. https://github.com/ComputerWolf/SlickNav/blob/master/slicknav.css

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
  .js #menu {
  display:none;
  }
.js .slicknav_menu {
  display:block;
  }
}
```

You should have this in your css. If you want the slicknav to show up on desktop you can change the max-width: 40em to a larger width, whatever the largest size you wish. I haven't tried it but you might be able to set it at 100%.